# Displaying menu based on login status

Tags: menus

I'm trying to show one menu based on whether or not the user is logged in. It's straight forward enough but when I change to my code I have no styles or icons like the original - see code below

ORIGINAL CODE (Menu looks fine)

```
<div id="main-menu">
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'sf-menu',         
'walker' => new header_one_uou_nav_menu) );?>
</div>
```

MY CODE (Will show correct menu based on login but with no icons and formatting)

```
<div id="main-menu">
<?php 

if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
$menu = 'menu_LI';
} else {
$menu = 'sf-menu';
}

wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $menu, 'container_class' => 'menu-header',
'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' ) );

?>


</div>
```

[Link](http://www.fantastickids.co.za) to  menu for reference of what it is supposed to look like

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, there are some pretty obvious differences between the original and your code, like:

- the use of a `walker`

  - this is most certainly needed for the fancy styling
- the lost and empty `menu_id` parameter

  - depending on the according CSS this might be needed too
- the use of the `menu` parameter

  - ok, to switch the menu displayed we need this
- addition of of a `container_class`

  - could possibly influence how the menu is displayed, depends on the CSS

That said, try this:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $menu = 'menu_LI';
} else {
    $menu = 'sf-menu';
}

wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'menu'            => $menu,
        'container_class' => 'menu-header',
        'theme_location'  => 'primary',
        'menu_id'         => 'sf-menu',
        'walker'          => new header_one_uou_nav_menu
    )
);
```

Furthermore you might have to adjust or play around with the parameters to get this working perfectly. Take above list as starting point and you might want to read the [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) again and possibly take a look at how the `Walker` thing works.

Comment: Ok thanks man - For now i have only one menu element that i wanted to hide so i have created a new page template for that page and added an if statement at the top of the page and a die statement as the else with a login message requiring login. Will try your suggestion and once i have it tuned up i will post back. thanks again

Comment: My pleasure. Sure, report back the progress, it's always helpful. @anthonytherockjohnson